# Como concatenar valores de tipos diferentes em uma string?

Tags: c++, string, concatenação-de-string

Como faço pra concatenar toda esta `string` dentro de uma variável? Tem alguma forma mais elegante de resolver o meu problema?

```
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 2;
int num3 = 3;
char simbol1 = '+';
char simbol2 = '-'; 

string equation = num1 + " " + simbol1 + " ( " + num3 + " " + simbol2 + " " + num3 + " ) = ? ";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que seja isto que quer:

```
auto equation = to_string(num1) + " " + simbol1 + " ( " + to_string(num2) + " " + simbol2 + " " + to_string(num2) + " ) = ? ";
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/String/Concatenation.cpp).

Precisa converter o número para `string` antes de concatenar.

Comment: Exatamente isso. Obrigado.

Comment: @MarkusBranco veja o [tour] como dizer obrigado da melhor forma. Você pode votar em tudo no site.